# Which way to initialize NSString* pointer in class

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm using `NSString` in my classes and often need to copy string value to another class. But my question is how should I initialize string in, for example `init`? 
(value is class member and the following calls are in init)

```
value = [NSString stringWithCString:inStrning encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

or

```
value = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:inStrning encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

What is the difference here? Does a memory allocated in 1st call released when init finishes?
I'm using `value` as a `assign` property. Would it be better to use `copy`?

And what about copying string when I'm passing it to class using some method? Example:

```
-(id) initWithObjectTypeStr:(NSString*)inTypeStr
{
    ...
    objectTypeStr = [NSString stringWithString:inType];
    //or 
    objectTypeStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:inType];
}
```

`objectTypeStr` is not defined as property so it has default properties (`assign` I think).

What is the best practice to use in this case?

Comment: see my blog post on memory management for this - http://www.makebetterthings.com/blogs/iphone/memory-management-in-objective-c-iphone/

Answer (score 2):

```
[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""]
```

Gives back a string you own, you will have to release it.

```
[NSString stringWithString:@""]
```

Returns an autorelease object that will release and cleaned up by the autoreleasepool.

I would suggest you read the [memory management documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000127i).

Comment: Thanks, that cleared a lot. Apple guides are more readable when I read them with focus on my problem.

Comment: The link is unfortunately dead now.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in this case `objectTypeStr = [NSString stringWithString:inType];`
`objectTypeStr` is auto-released and you dont own the object.

Whereas in `objectTypeStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:inType];`
you take ownership of the object since you are allocating it using alloc or new so its your responsibility to release it after its use