# NSMutableArray initialization behavior

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

When I initialize

```
self.nsmutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

in my viewDidLoad method NSMutableArray initialize correctly and i can addObject inside it. But if i skip the above initialization in viewDidLoad method and initialize it in some other methods, NSMutableArray initialize incorrectly and i can not addObject inside it. 
Why this behavior. Is it need to be initialized in viewDidLoad always?

Comment: What are "SOME OTHER METHODS" ?

Comment: You may want to review the [Objective-C Primer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is almost a duplicate question. Your issue has little to do with the `NSMutableArray` initialization and more to do with how you conduct memory management in Objective-C on subclasses of `NSObject` in general.

See related post on `NSString`s [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580294/which-way-to-initialize-nsstring-pointer-in-class). Look at the top answer.

If you want the array to last for the lifetime of the class, try: 
`self.nsmutablearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`
Just make sure you release it in the `dealloc` method:
`[self.nsmutablearray release];`

Alternatively, you could `@synthesize` nsmutablearray, but you would still need to handle its release. There are a myriad of ways to address this issue.

Comment: You did not get my point. I know how to initialize something... Maybe trying to understand iOS platform a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialize a NSMutableArray in your viewDidLoad message. In fact your NSMutableArray has no knowledge of the context in which it is being initialized.

I would investigate the specifics of the problems you are having when you try to subsequently add objects to the array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is weired to me but now i am sure that I don't need to initialize in viewDidLoad. Maybe something else I am not getting here.